# ASP.NET WebForms/jQuery: jQuery .click event on button keeps button's serverside OnClick event from firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, events, webforms

I am trying to disable a button as soon as it is clicked to prevent double clicking.  The following Javascript does the job:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=cmTest.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});
```

Here's my button:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmTest" Text="Test" runat="server" />
```

Here's my VB:

```
Private Sub cmTest_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmTest.Click

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

End Sub
```

Whenever the jQuery .click event is assigned to the button, the clientside functionality works, but the serverside event never runs.  When I remove the jQuery, the serverside event executes.  It's almost like I've assigned `onclick=javascript:DisableButton();return false;` to the button itself.  Is there any way to assign that Javascript to the button while also allowing the serverside event to be triggered?

**Edit:** So it's not *exactly* like assigning `return false;` to the button since the page still posts back.  Doing `return false;` actually cancels the button's submit which is not what's happening here.

Comment: I would assume the serverside event isn't firing because the button is disabled.  If you want to limit the click to once, why not do something like onClick = if ( window.myClickPerformed ) { return false; } else { window.myClickPerformed = true; }

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your form element

```
onsubmit="$(':submit').attr('disabled', 'true');"
```

If you have more than 1 submit button, you'll have to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled form elements are not included in the post.

As a result, your event is disabling the element before it is sent as a request, hiding it from ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

It won't execute because you disabled the button. Instead of disabling, You should probably change the look and feel of the button (apply a different CSS) so that user will feel that it is disabled. Set a session variable to some value as the first line of button click event. and everytime check if it is already set, don't execute the code then. Thus you prevent the double submit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the visibility to false.  It's not quite the same as disabling the button, but it has the functionality, and it doesn't run into that problem of being unable to click a disabled button.

You could even replace it with an loading image.